# GameAnalytics.setEnabledInfoLog(true) doesn't print anything in Xcode console

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, fabric.io, gameanalytics

I'm trying to configure GameAnalytics for my iOS app (swift). In the [doc](https://github.com/GameAnalytics/GA-SDK-IOS/wiki/Debugging) it says to call GameAnalytics.setEnabledInfoLog(true) to print debugging informations, but it doesn't print anything in Xcode console.

I can see the events in the Live feed on [GameAnalytics.com](https://gameanalytics.com) but there's a long delay before they show up. It's not really live. How can I see the events in Xcode's console?

Comment: Try `verbose`, may be the SDK isn't printing anything... And it takes time, because the SDK sends data to server in regular intervals. May be there is predefined interval in the SDK.

Comment: I have both GameAnalytics.setEnabledInfoLog(true) and GameAnalytics.setEnabledVerboseLog(true) and I still have nothing in the console. I was expecting to see the debug info in realtime even if there's a delay before it sends data to the server.